# Can I use Sql Server CE (3.0) as an embedded database for my windows application? Do I have to install Sql Server CE in the machine?

Tags: windows, database, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

I created a windows application and I needed a database for it. I first used `SQL Server Express` edition in it. Then I came to know that it is not exactly a portable database. That is, SQL Server Express edition should be already installed in the computer where I suppose to use my application. I came to know that I can use SQL CE instead and changed to it. I found somewhere that all I have to do is just copy the `sqlceme30.dll` in the application. Worked fine in my developement system. But when I copy the application to another system and open the application, it throws the error

```
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can I use SQL CE in my application? I really don't want to install it in all the machines I use my app. Or if not, which other db I can use without intalling? Access?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your reference is set to `Copy Local`. Right click on the reference, and click properties. They change the `Copy Local` property to `true`. That will ensure that the dll is included in the publish.

Comment: Will my application work if I do this? I mean, can I use Sql Server CE as a portable DB for my app? without installing it on the target systems?

Comment: Also, I haven't added any reference- I just included the namespace in the code. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, add the reference and do as I suggest. Then the SQLCE db file should work without an client installation.

Comment: I did the same, created an installer for it and installed on the machine. But still. I am getting the same error message.